# Twilio: limit number of outbound calls

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am currently working with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) and NodeJS.

I am building sort of a dialer that loops over an object and makes outbound calls.

I would like to find a way to limit the number of ongoing calls to a certain number e.g. 5 calls at a time.

Ideas so far,

- store a status variable on my object (list of people to call) and before going to the next iteration count the number of ongoing call if <5, continue if >5 wait x secs.
- before each iteration, make a request to Twilio to know the number of ongoing call on Twilio side and then continue if

Here is my code:

```
function loopSession() {
    logger.info('Starting looping over sessions')

    async.forEach(Object.keys(sessions.returnAllSessions()), function (sessionKey, callback) {

        let session = sessions.returnSingleSession(sessionKey);

        logger.debug('Processing :' + session.user.mobileNo + ' started');

        // CONDITION TO HAVE LESS THAN 5 ONGOING CALLS 

        callClient(session.user.mobileNo); // should be async? 

        logger.debug('Processing :' + session.user.mobileNo + ' done')
        callback();

    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            logger.debug(err);
        } else {
            logger.info('Iterating over session done');
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried those ideas so far? Did one work?

Comment: I switched to Python for the dialer part

Comment: Ok, but is your code working or is there a specific problem?